# Grails 2.5 cannot locate image path in js file

Tags: html, grails, asset-pipeline

I'm using asset pipeline in Grails 2.5.x. I'm put the img folder which contains images into asset folder.

However in js file, I cannot use `<assets:image` tag in the image path.

For example:

```
controlHTML: '<img src="../img/up.png" style="width:40px; height:40px" />'
```

I can get to the path but in web inspect element, the path is incorrect: `'localhost:9090/CardReg/img/up.png'`

Error when I put

```
controlHTML: '<img src="<asset:image src='../img/up.png'/>" style="width:40px; height:40px" />'
```

Any ideas?

Any solutions will be appreciated. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Grails tags are not usable from within a .js context. Only from within a .gsp

I would recommend putting

```
<asset:script>
    var contextPath = "${request.contextPath}";
</asset:script>
```

In your main gsp layout file, and then from your js you can reference images via

```
var myImage = contextPath + "/assets/myImage.jpg"
```

I also recommend practicing smart javascript, so you might want to put any of these layout variables declared into an object to act as a namespace.

Also make sure that the script block is the very first script imported.